# Which version of python ROS kinetic is compatible with

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello every one

I am new to ROS and python as well and I am wondering which version of python is compatible with ROS kinetic or it doesn't matter?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269143/which-version-of-python-ros-kinetic-is-compatible-with/) by [ShehabAldeen](https://answers.ros.org/users/31455/shehabaldeen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2017-08-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In short: Python 2.7.

Some related Q&As: #q237613 and #q262551.

And [REP-3 - Target Platforms - Kinetic Kame](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#kinetic-kame-may-2016-may-2021) for the official documentation.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0